# Windows: Pre-boot disk logging from BIOS

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way for systems to log the type of disks (boot disks) that were not loaded because of BIOS settings forcing the system to boot from the HDD?

**Example:** Let's say someone tried to load a insert some kind of bootable disc (Knoppix/WinPE/whatever) on a machine, but it was bypassed due to the boot order skipping external/optical drives. Could this information (that a disk was in fact in the tray) be logged in some scenario?

It's probably bad practice for the disk to even spin up to get any kind of info off of it for the sake of logging, but to a lesser extent, is this something that could be tracked (that there even was a disk present) at such a low level?Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No.

Long Answer: Drives/Boot options lower in boot priority aren't checked by BIOS/UEFI, to avoid boot delay, and thus the system doesn't know and doesn't care if any external bootable devices/disks are present.

From a security standpoint, the saying goes "With physical access, all bets are off" meaning boot order is not a viable security measure as such a thing is easy to change when physically at the machine. Even without cooperation of the machine the drives themselves are at the mercy of someone physically able to obtain/manipulate them. Boot order is a nice gesture but ensuring someone you don't trust is unable to get to the physical machine is paramount to good security.

Comment: Thank you -- so, despite if someone had _tried_ to maybe load some kind of disk (this is specifically a Lenevo box), it probably wasn't written down somewhere, merely bypassed.

Comment: If a skilled individual was at the machine trying to load up something, they could load it up, and have the compromised machine tell you that it wasn't compromised. Again physical security goes a long way.

Comment: Okay, interesting, and thank you -- I'm assuming that its not common practice for most enterprise type implementations to have any kind of logging when someone has tried to simply boot from a different device, since its just disregarded at POST/etc.

Comment: No, it is not common practice to audit/log boot attempts. In an enterprise setting workstations are locked down to prevent booting from external devices, this makes logging/auditing boot attempts from an unauthorized boot device/disk unnecessary. 

As for what auditing is/can be done of boot up, Secure Boot and UEFI offer "Managed Boot" whose purpose is to audit the entire boot chain to ensure files and firmware haven't been changed/compromised by malware or a root kit.